# Can i using only SimpleJSON upload and send photo in Telegram? C#

Tags: c#, telegram

I know that this is a pretty stupid question, but is it still possible to use standard libraries and SimpleJSON.

Comment: Yes.  A photo is binary do make sure you convert to base 64 string : Convert.ToBase64String(byte[])

Comment: This not works, i have a path to photo only, if i using Convert.ToBase64String,i have a error(converting a type from "string" to "byte []" is not possible).

Comment: You must convert the photo to a byte[] before using Convert.

Comment: Error: (413) Request Entity Too Large.
Photo code: [link](http://imgur.com/a/xDHkm)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can see [this document](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sending-files):

> There are three ways to send files (photos, stickers, audio, media, etc.):
>
> 1.If the file is already stored somewhere on the Telegram servers, you don't need to reupload it: each file object has a file_id field, simply pass this file_id as a parameter instead of uploading. There are no limits for files sent this way.
>
> 2.Provide Telegram with an HTTP URL for the file to be sent. Telegram will download and send the file. 5 MB max size for photos and 20 MB max for other types of content.
>
> 3.Post the file using multipart/form-data in the usual way that files are uploaded via the browser. 10 MB max size for photos, 50 MB for other files.

The third method is what you want.

Comment: And how i do this? I can't search a example.

Comment: @МаксимЮкифагов You need to search for uploading file, it is another question